# How to install SmartSVN on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java, smartsvn

I want to install [SmartSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartSVN) on Ubuntu. I have installed the latest `sun-java6-jre` package, but still I am getting such errors as

> An incompatible Java version has been detected which has been reported to
>   cause strange bugs. Aborting now.
>
> Please install the latest release of the SUN Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE)
>   from:
>
> http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/
>
> or if it is already installed, make sure it is used.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you also have another Java runtime installed and haven't set up the Sun JRE as the default. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to change the default JRE, or give SmartSVN the full path to the Sun JRE (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java`).

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the default JRE and it started working.